# "Hello world" program not running

Tags: c

I typed this program on code blocks but it is showing error on int main line
Here's the program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 printf("Hello");
 return 0;
 }
```

The message return is " multiple definition of main"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: There is no problem with the posted code. This is probably an IDE misconfiguration error, or similar. With just this information this can't be answered. → _close as unclear_

Comment: In your Code:Blocks project, do you have multiple source files? Do more than one of the source files contain a `main` function?

Comment: Is this the only file in your project? Is there any other file with a `main()`?

Comment: Yes this is the only file in my project and I use GNU GCC complier on Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code is correct. It might be an IDE configuration error. Use **gcc** to compile your code on Linux and on Windows you can install **MinGW** and execute from a command window.